# Issues setting display resolution on Firefly RK-3288 board

Tags: linux, ubuntu, linux-kernel, ubuntu-14.04, xorg

I have a RK-3288 Firefly board (which is running Ubuntu 14.04.5 LTS) and I'm running into issues getting the correct display resolution over HDMI. It looks like i'm getting 720p, which is then upscaled to 1080p and looks horrible. If I instead plug in a VGA cable it looks good.

I've tried forcing the HDMI to 1080p but I'm having issues. It looks like xrandr does not properly detect the HDMI port:

```
sudo xrandr --newmode "1920x1080_60.00"  173.00  1920 2048 2248 2576  1080 1083 1088 1120 -hsync +vsync
xrandr: Failed to get size of gamma for output default


sudo xrandr --addmode HDMI-0 1920x1080_60.60
xrandr: Failed to get size of gamma for output default
xrandr: cannot find output "HDMI-0"


sudo xrandr --query
xrandr: Failed to get size of gamma for output default
Screen 0: minimum 1920 x 1080, current 1920 x 1080, maximum 1920 x 1080
default connected 1920x1080+0+0 0mm x 0mm
   1920x1080      60.0* 
  1920x1080_60.00 (0x6c)  173.0MHz
        h: width  1920 start 2048 end 2248 total 2576 skew    0 clock   67.2KHz
        v: height 1080 start 1083 end 1088 total 1120           clock   60.0Hz
```

I've downloaded all available updates using "apt-get update/upgrade". Additional commands that I've tried:

```
firefly@firefly:~$ sudo lspci
pcilib: Cannot open /proc/bus/pci
lspci: Cannot find any working access method.

firefly@firefly:~$ sudo lshw -C display

firefly@firefly:~$ cat /etc/X11/xorg.conf.d/*
Section "InputClass"
        Identifier "gslX680 evdev touchscreen"
        MatchProduct    "gslX680"
        MatchDevicePath "/dev/input/event*"
        Option "EmulateThirdButton" "true"
        Option "EmulateThirdButtonTimeout" "500"
        Option "EmulateThirdButtonMoveThreshold" "50"
        Driver "evdev"
EndSection
Section "InputClass"
        Identifier "evdev gsl680"
        #MatchIsTouchscreen "on"
        MatchProduct "gsl680"
        MatchDevicePath "/dev/input/event*"
        Driver "evdev"
EndSection
```

Thanks for your time

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved it myself by upgrading my Linux dist to Ubuntu 16.04 (Beta) release which had been ported for the Firefly board